# Parsley JS Not Equal To Multiple IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, parsley.js

I have a form with multiple select boxes and need to ensure that the same value is not set across any of them. For example, if select box 1 is set to 2, and select box 4 is also set to 2, I should receive an error. I can get this working with a single ID but cannot get it to work with multiple IDs separated by a comma.

The other requirement is that I need Parsley to validate on .change once the user has corrected the error and without needing to submit the form again.

The code that works for only a single ID is:

```html
window.Parsley.addValidator("notequalto", {
    requirementType: "string",
    validateString: function(value, element) {
        return value !== $(element).val();
    }
});
```

The validation code I currently have is:

```html
var validating;

$("#postorg").parsley();

$('#series_post_order1').change(()=>{
 if(!validating) return; $("#postorg").parsley().validate({group:'postorder'});
});
$('#series_post_order2').change(()=>{
 if(!validating) return; $("#postorg").parsley().validate({group:'postorder'});
});
$('#series_post_order3').change(()=>{
 if(!validating) return; $("#postorg").parsley().validate({group:'postorder'});
});
$('#series_post_order4').change(()=>{
 if(!validating) return; $("#postorg").parsley().validate({group:'postorder'});
});

window.Parsley.addValidator("notequalto", {
      validateMultiple: function(values) {
        return values.length > 0;
      },
    requirementType: "string",
    validateString: function(value, element) {
     var els=element.split(',');
     for(let i=0;i<els.length;i++){
       if (jQuery(els[i]).val()){
        return value !== $(element).val();
       }
     }
      return true;
   },
   priority: 33
});
```

and the form looks like this:

```html
<form name="series_edit_postorg" id="postorg" method="post" action="series_postorg">

<div class="formbig-mobile">

<select name="series_post_order1" class="select" id="series_post_order1" data-parsley-group="postorder" data-parsley-notequalto="#series_post_order2,#series_post_order3,#series_post_order4" data-parsley-notequalto-message="Each post must have a different number">
<option value="1" selected>1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select name="series_post_order2" class="select" id="series_post_order2" data-parsley-group="postorder" data-parsley-notequalto="#series_post_order1,#series_post_order3,#series_post_order4" data-parsley-notequalto-message="Each post must have a different number">
<option value="2" selected>2</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
</div>

<select name="series_post_order3" class="select" id="series_post_order3" data-parsley-group="postorder" data-parsley-notequalto="#series_post_order1,#series_post_order2,#series_post_order4" data-parsley-notequalto-message="Each post must have a different number">
<option value="3" selected>3</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
</div>

<select name="series_post_order4" class="select" id="series_post_order4" data-parsley-group="postorder" data-parsley-notequalto="#series_post_order1,#series_post_order2,#series_post_order3" data-parsley-notequalto-message="Each post must have a different number">
<option value="4" selected>4</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPDATE" class="selectbutton">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer to solve this:

```html
var validating;

$("#postorg").parsley();

$('.select').change(()=>{
if(!validating) return; $("#postorg").parsley().validate({group:'postorder'});
});

window.Parsley.addValidator("notequalto", {
      validateMultiple: function(values) {
        return values.length > 0;
      },
    requirementType: "string",
    validateString: function(value, requirement) {
      validating = true;
      var $otherElements = $(requirement);
      var duplicateFound = false;
      
      $otherElements.each(function(){
        duplicateFound = duplicateFound || this.value === value;
      });
      
      return !duplicateFound;
   },
   priority: 33
});
```